# RequireJS: Load module from other context

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have two require configurations (two context) like this:

```
var requirePortal = require.config({
    context: 'portal',
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'assets/js-vendors/jquery/dist/jquery',
        'underscore': 'assets/js-vendors/underscore/underscore',
        'backbone': 'assets/js-vendors/backbone/backbone',
        // ...
    }
});

var requireSample = require.config({
    context: 'sample',
    baseUrl: '<adress>/other-context',
    paths: {
        'viewFactory': 'application/util/ViewFactory',
        'indicador':   'application/models/indicador'
    }
});
```

Here portal context will have all vendors components, and sample context will have use case modules. Then I must load vendor components from sample context like that:

```
define([
    'indicador'
], function(IndicadorModel) {
    var IndicadorPagerCollection = PagerCollection.extend({
        model: IndicadorModel,
        baseUrl: 'rest/manter/indicadores'
    });
    return IndicadorPagerCollection;
});
```

In this case, `PagerCollection` is a vendor component and is in portal context. How can I do this?